# svn log retrieve between the lines where find specific word

Tags: svn, sed, awk, grep

I want to extract from SVN log all text between the lines. If it is with sed, awk or grep it's better.

Example: **svn.log**

```
------------------------------------------------------------------------
r1075 | popad | 2011-12-02 14:28:20 +0200 (Fri, 02 Dec 2011) | 1 line
Changed paths:
   M /trunk/apps/frontend/modules/mail/templates/candidateSearchAgentSuccess.php
   M /trunk/apps/test.php

Ticket #1000: removing ads from emails
------------------------------------------------------------------------
r1074 | coman | 2011-11-30 10:51:29 +0200 (Wed, 30 Nov 2011) | 3 lines
Changed paths:
M /trunk/apps/frontend/i18n/messages.de.xml
M /trunk/apps/frontend/i18n/messages.en.xml
M /trunk/apps/frontend/i18n/messages.ro.xml

Ticket #1089: translation update: send to friend form
http://example.com/projects/147/tickets/1089
Solved HU translation update


------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

I want to search for **Ticket #1000** and retrieve **entire block between the lines**

```
------------------------------------------------------------------------
r1075 | popad | 2011-12-02 14:28:20 +0200 (Fri, 02 Dec 2011) | 1 line
Changed paths:
   M /trunk/apps/frontend/saSuccess.php
   M /trunk/apps/frontend/saAddSuccess.php

Ticket #1000: removing ads from emails
------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

this awk oneliner gives you the output you need:

```
awk -vRS='-+\n' '/Ticket #1000/' svn.log
```

**test**

```
kent$  awk -vRS='-+\n' '/Ticket #1000/' svn.log 

r1075 | popad | 2011-12-02 14:28:20 +0200 (Fri, 02 Dec 2011) | 1 line
Changed paths:
   M /trunk/apps/frontend/modules/mail/templates/candidateSearchAgentSuccess.php
   M /trunk/apps/test.php

Ticket #1000: removing ads from emails
```

You have seen that the line separator (-----) was not in output. it could be easily added if you really need.

Comment: +1 from me. This is clearly the neatest approach and the easiest to understand. Mine prints the line separators, though ;)

Comment: @danielpopa: "Thanks. This helps a lot!" is best expressed "[by clicking on the check box outline to the left of the answer.](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask)"

Comment: As you can see my scoring, I'm a beginner. So, you can help me, also by clicking the left upper arrow on my question ;)

Comment: @danielpopa: If you hover over that little arrow, you'll see it says "This question shows research effort". I'm afraid I can't click it.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest to use the xml output of svn log and extract the information from the xml file instead..might be simpler...

```
svn log --xml ...
```

Answer (score 1):

Interesting exercise, so I had a go!

```
% awk ' 
{
    lines = lines "\n" $0
}

/Ticket #1000/ {
    found = 1
}

/^-+$/ {
    if (found) {
        print lines
    }
    lines = $0
    found = 0
}
' svn.log
------------------------------------------------------------------------
r1075 | popad | 2011-12-02 14:28:20 +0200 (Fri, 02 Dec 2011) | 1 line
Changed paths:
   M /trunk/apps/frontend/modules/mail/templates/candidateSearchAgentSuccess.php
   M /trunk/apps/test.php

Ticket #1000: removing ads from emails
------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

I think this is pretty self-explanatory but will update the answer if it's not.

This works even when more than one commit contains the search string.

Making the search string variable is left as an exercise.

Tested using:

```
% awk --version
awk version 20070501
```

I prefer to avoid one-liners. If you like that sort of thing, then you'll need semicolons between statements.

Comment: There is a reason why all params are not on the same line. It gave me syntax error.

Comment: Excellent. Works great: awk v3.1.6.

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you:

```
 sed '/^-\+$/{h;:a;$d;N;/-\+$/!ba;/Ticket #1000:/p;g;ba};d' svn.log
```